# Import a file from Reports folder in the SFTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, reports-folder, sftp

I want to implement a process in which, once the Report is exported to the SFTP /Reports folder, it will be imported to a Data Extension.

How can I move the file to another folder in order to be able to import it? Is there any feature that has to be enabled for that purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create data extract activity using 'Enhanced FTP File Move and Copy' extract type, it will help you to move/copy the file from one folder to another. Then you can create import activity to import the same file into your data extension.

To enable this data extract type, you will need to create a ticket with salesforce marketing cloud support team.

[image: Data Extract activity_1]

[image: Data Extract activity_2]

Comment: As a note, I do not believe that using this will activate a File Triggered Automation when the file is moved.

Comment: No, it will not trigger the automation, however we can use those 2 activities in schedule automation.

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to make sure it was noted. The solution is valid and I have +1'd accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I already asked to support to enable this extract type. As I don't need to activate the File Triggered Automation this solution should be fine. I will do it in a scheduled way. @Gortonington